# Error ContextSwitchDeadlock al abrir un formulario hijo c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excepciones

Tengo el siguiente método que se ejecuta al cerrar el formulario y se queda en una especie de loop y lanza el error ContextSwitchDeadlock, el error tambien se suscita cuando doy en el boton actualizar.

```
    private void BtnActualiza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        daoPac.Eliminar_Espacio_Nombre_Paciente(txtNombre);
        daoPac.Eliminar_Espacio_Apellido_Paciente(txtApellido);
       
        Frm_Listado_Paciente frm = new Frm_Listado_Paciente
        {
            MdiParent = MdiParent
        };
        frm.Show();
        Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

En el método formclosing sucede lo mismo pero si comento estas lineas el error no aparece y me permite guardar sin problema alguno y no cae en ese loop

```
     private void Frm_Edicion_Paciente_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         Form frml = MdiChildren.FirstOrDefault(x => x is Frm_Listado_Paciente);

         if (daoVar.FormIsOpen("Frm_Listado_Paciente") == true)
         {
             //  MessageBox.Show("El Formulario ya esta Abierto", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
             return;
         }
         else if (frml != null)
         {
             //si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano                        
             frml.BringToFront();
             return;
         }
         else if (frml == null)
         {
             Frm_Listado_Paciente frm = new Frm_Listado_Paciente
             {
                 MdiParent = MdiParent
             };
             frm.Show();
             Close();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     }
 }
```

Se llama al método FormIsOpen pongo el código.

```
   public bool FormIsOpen(string FormABuscar)
  {
      Boolean lEncontrado = false;
      foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
      {
          if (form.Name == FormABuscar)
          {
              form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
              form.Activate();
              lEncontrado = true;
              break;
          }
      }
      return lEncontrado;
  }
```

Por ultimo el método cancelar.

```
     private void BtnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
     Frm_Listado_Paciente frm = new Frm_Listado_Paciente
     {
         MdiParent = MdiParent
     };
     frm.Show();
     Close();
 }
```

Que podría estar realizando erróneamente, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Se requiere más código o más contexto, ya que no consigo replicar tu error, ya sea la clase de daoVar o la estructura de controles que tienes escrita, como a apunte en hacer vueltas al application.Openforms el segundo en la lista, el name del form me salía vacío, lo que al final he probado de validar por texto

Comment: @rexxarcat edite la pregunta para que tenga idea de como funciona.

Comment: He estado probando, perdón por tardar tanto, por lo que veo el código no tiene ningún problema, ya que me funciona correctamente, he investigado un poco y te recomiendo que pruebes lo siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578357/visual-studio-contextswitchdeadlock),  al ser un aviso de VS se puede llegar a ignorar si salta cuando no toca.

Comment: @rexxarcat buscando otra cosa encontré la solución , resulta ser que el nombre del formulario se encuentra `Frm_Listado_Paciente` pero resulta ser que lo guarde con minúscula `frm_Listado_Paciente` cambie ejecute y funciono sin problema.

Comment: me alegro de que lo hayas podido solucionar, saludos.